# Correcting confidence intervals for multiple comparisons using the multcomp package

Tags: r

In [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114879/should-we-address-multiple-comparisons-adjustments-when-using-confidence-interva?rq=1) excellent post on cross validated an answer mentioned that it is relatively easy to correct confidence intervals for multiple comparisons.

I am wondering whether this is possible using the multcomp package in R

Here's an example model using the `mtcars` dataset from base R, a multivariate regression predicting miles per gallon (`mpg`) from a list of predictors.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- mtcars

# which variables predict miles per gallon?
sumMod <- summary(mod <- lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + gear,
                            data = df))
```

Now run the model through the `multcomp` package using the `glht` function.

```
# adjust using multcomp
library(multcomp)
K <- length(coefficients(mod))
modGLHT <- glht(model = mod,
                linfct = diag(K))
```

In `multcomp` you choose the method of adjustment using the `test = adjusted(type = 'foo')` argument within the package's `summary()` function

```
sumNone <- summary(modGLHT, test = adjusted(type = "none")) # no adjustment
sumSingleStep <- summary(modGLHT, test = adjusted(type = "single-step")) # single-step method
```

Now if we compare the p-value for the `wt` coefficient under no correction and with single-step correction...

```
data.frame(correction = c("none", "single-step"),
           coefs = c(round(sumNone$test$coefficients[6],2),
                     round(sumSingleStep$test$coefficients[6],2)),
           p = c(round(sumNone$test$pvalues[6],3),
                 round(sumSingleStep$test$pvalues[6],3)))

 # output
 #   correction coefs     p
 #         none -4.36 0.003
 #  single-step -4.36 0.024
```

We can see that the p-value has increased after applying single-step correction. So far so good.

My issue is **how to get corrected confidence intervals?**

I tried applying `adjusted(type = 'foo')` within the `confint()` function (once again for illustration I have focused on the `wt` predictor) like so...

```
# get CIs using four different methods
ciNone <- round(as.data.frame(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = "none"))$confint)[6,],3)
ciSS <- round(as.data.frame(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = "single-step"))$confint)[6,],3)
ciShaffer <- round(as.data.frame(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = "Shaffer"))$confint)[6,],3)
ciWestfall <- round(as.data.frame(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = "Westfall"))$confint)[6,],3)

# put them all together for comparison
cbind(data.frame(correction = c("None", "Single_Step", "Shaffer", "Westfall")),
      rbind(ciNone, ciSS, ciShaffer, ciWestfall))

# output
#     correction Estimate    lwr    upr
# 6         None   -4.356 -8.274 -0.439
# 61 Single_Step   -4.356 -8.269 -0.444
# 62     Shaffer   -4.356 -8.276 -0.437
# 63    Westfall   -4.356 -8.279 -0.434
```

No it looks to me as if *something* is going on, there are some very small differences. But when I run the `confint()` function on its own and ...

```
confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = "Shaffer"))
```

the output makes no mention anywhere of type of error correction. I also get no error message. So I can't tell if the `adjusted(type = 'foo')` argument is doing anything nor whether the above differences in the CIs using the different methods are actual differences due to the method itself or simply an artefact of some randomness in a Markov-type procedure used to generate the intervals.

So **is it legitimate to add the `adjusted(type = 'foo')` argument to the `confint()` function in `multcomp`?**. The help documentation for the function does not say so and although I got no error message when I did it I cannot tell if it worked.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look at `View(multcomp:::confint.glht)` and `View(adjusted)`? `confint.glht` is not directly exported, but tells you what `confint` does if you apply it to a an object of type `glht`.

Comment: Thanks for responding @tester. When I ran `View(multcomp:::confint.glht)` it threw an error `Error in View : 'confint.glht' is not an exported object from 'namespace:multcomp'`. I am not sure what you mean by "`confint.glht` is not directly exported"?

Comment: If you mean the help for `confint.glht` it is quite generic, applying to multiple functions under the umbrella 'glht-methods'. And although it describes the `type` argument, when you use `type = ` in `multcomp::confint()` it throws an error saying that argument is ignored.

Comment: I meant checking the source code of `confint.glht` and `adjusted`. The former is the fourth function here https://rdrr.io/rforge/multcomp/src/R/methods.R.

Comment: Thank you @tester I tried viewing it but kept getting the error. A lot of the code is over my head but it looks like the CIs are calculated by adjusting the ses using with an adjusted alpha passed into the `confint()` function via the `calpha()` argument, e.g. `UpperCL <- betahat + calpha * ses`. Is that your take, and do you think that means the regular CIs *are* adjusted by calpha?

Comment: In the help for `adjusted_calpha` is says "Simultaneous confidence intervals for linear functions can be computed using method confint. Univariate confidence intervals can be computed by specifying calpha = univariate_calpha() to confint." Now I am wondering what univariate confidence intervals are and how they differ from adjusted. I tried `confint(modGLHT, calpha = univariate_calpha())` and `confint(modGLHT, calpha = adjusted_calpha())` and in the output the former has a quantile of 2.05 whereas the latter has a quantile of 2.95.

Comment: So I guess univariate are unadjusted confidence intervals, whereas adjusted involve some sort of adjustment. But is there any way to specify the *type* of adjustment. Every answer begets a new question it seems. Feels like I am getting closer to an answer though so thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't specify *type* of adjustment when computing confidence intervals with *multcomp*. As discussed in the comments, you can choose between individual confidence intervals and simultaneous confidence intervals.

- *Individual* confidence intervals: Control the coverage probability of each confidence interval separately, ie., *each* confidence interval will contain the true parameter 100(1-α)% times if the experiment is repeated.
- *Simultaneous* confidence intervals: Control the overall coverage probability, ie, *all* confidence intervals will contain their true parameter 100(1-α)% times if the experiment is repeated. This corresponds to family-wise error rate FWER = α because the probability of one or more false discoveries (type I errors) is α. [However, simultaneous CIs are not equivalent to Bonferroni correction; see the update below.]

*multcomp* takes into account the correlations between hypotheses to get the coverage of simultaneous confidence intervals right and that's all the adjustment needed. The documentation is somewhat clear about all this.

To compute p-values, use the `summary` function on a `glht` object and specify how to adjust the p-values with the `test = adjusted(type = "method")` argument. The available methods include "single-step" (the default) and "bonferroni".

To compute confidence intervals, use the `confint` function of a `glht` object and specify how to compute the critical value with the `calpha` argument. There are two options: `univariate_calpha()` to compute univariate confidence intervals and `adjusted_calpha()` to compute simultaneous confidence intervals. Basically, `confint` ignores the `type = "method"` argument, if provided.

If *multcomp* doesn't adjust simultaneous confidence intervals, why does it seem that *something* is going on? It's because there is randomness in the computation of the critical value, *calpha*.

*multcomp* uses `mvtnorm::qmvt` to compute *calpha*, which in turn uses as a stochastic algorithm to find the quantiles a multivariate normal distribution.

In effect this is what you did: You fix the random seed once and call a stochastic function multiple times. You get slightly different critical values.

```
set.seed(1234)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
```

Instead fix the seed before calling the stochastic function. You get exactly the same critical value each time and the simultaneous confidence intervals won't change.

```
set.seed(1234)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
set.seed(1234)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
set.seed(1234)
calpha <- qmvt(level, ...)
```

Let's demonstrate this on your example.

```r
library("broom")
library("multcomp")
library("tidyverse")

options(
  pillar.sigfig = 5
)

mod <- lm(
  formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + gear,
  data = mtcars
)

# Usually we aren't interested in testing that the intercept is 0.
# So let's skip it.
K <- diag(length(coef(mod)))[-1, ]
rownames(K) <- names(coef(mod))[-1]
K
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#> cyl     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> disp    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> hp      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> drat    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#> wt      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> qsec    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> vs      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> gear    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1

modGLHT <- glht(
  model = mod,
  linfct = K
)

methods <- c("none", "single-step", "Shaffer", "Westfall")
names(methods) <- methods
```

There is randomness in computing the critical value, `calpha`. So we get slightly different simultaneous confidence intervals for the same set of hypotheses.

```r
set.seed(1234)

methods %>%
  map_dfr(

    # `confint` silently ignores `adjusted`
    ~ tidy(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = .))),
    .id = "method"
  ) %>%
  filter(
    contrast == "cyl"
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   method      contrast estimate conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 none        cyl      -0.52659  -3.3654    2.3122
#> 2 single-step cyl      -0.52659  -3.3665    2.3133
#> 3 Shaffer     cyl      -0.52659  -3.3670    2.3138
#> 4 Westfall    cyl      -0.52659  -3.3624    2.3093
```

We fix the random seed before computing the critical value `calpha`, so the simultaneous confidence intervals are computed in a reproducible way.

```r
methods %>%
  map_dfr(

    # `confint` silently ignores `adjusted`
    ~ {
      set.seed(1234)
      tidy(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = .)))
    },
    .id = "method"
  ) %>%
  filter(
    contrast == "cyl"
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   method      contrast estimate conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 none        cyl      -0.52659  -3.3648    2.3116
#> 2 single-step cyl      -0.52659  -3.3648    2.3116
#> 3 Shaffer     cyl      -0.52659  -3.3648    2.3116
#> 4 Westfall    cyl      -0.52659  -3.3648    2.3116
```

---

*Updates*

Bonferroni controls the familiy-wise error rate (FWER) at the α level and simultaneous confidence intervals are 100(1-α)% family-wise confidence intervals. So Bonferroni and simultaneous CIs have the FWER concept in common. But they are not equivalent. Why?

The Bonferroni method divides the p-values of *m* simultaneous hypotheses by *m*. The procedure is conservative: it guarantees that the FWER is *≤ α* rather than *= α* and it tends to over-correct, a lot.

In general, we don't know the dependencies between hypotheses. However, we do with regression because we have an estimate of the covariance matrix *Var{(β<sub>1</sub>, β<sub>2</sub>, ..., β<sub>p</sub>)}*. So we can estimate correlations between hypotheses which are functions of the model coefficients (such as *β<sub>1</sub> = 0*, *β<sub>2</sub> = 0*, ..., *β<sub>p</sub> = 0*).

And this is how *multcomp* computes simultaneous confidence intervals: it takes into account the correlations between hypotheses to correct the critical value *calpha* "just the right amount". While Bonferroni ignores this information to apply the most stringent correction.

---

The simultaneous confidence intervals are determined by the set of hypotheses being tested. Changing the *other* hypotheses can lead to a different confidence interval for the same individual hypothesis because the overall coverage depends in a complex way on the correlations between all hypotheses.

```r
set.seed(1234)

modGLHT <- glht(
  model = mod,
  linfct = c("cyl = 0", "disp = 0")
)

tidy(confint(modGLHT, adjusted(type = .)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   contrast  estimate  conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 cyl      -0.52659  -2.8330    1.7798  
#> 2 disp      0.016565 -0.014587  0.047716
```

Comment: Thank you for that incredibly well explained and well thought-out answer @dipetkov. I *thought* the differences I observed were due to stochasticity but it is a big relief to have that confirmed from someone who knows what they are on about. If I can prevail upon you for a quick follow-up. So is the FWER correction contained within the simultaneuous confidence intervals equivalent to a bonferroni correction? And is there any way in multcomp to obtain confidence intervals that have a different equivalent method of correction (e.g. false discovery rate), or a different package that does?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the `how_to_adjust_pvalues` function. Do you mean the `test = adjusted(type = "foo")` argument?

Comment: Is the `calpha = adjusted_calpha()` argument's correction of the CIs equivalent to the bonferroni correction for p-values?

Comment: Thanks for the followup questions as they can help me improve the answer. Very quickly: 1. Bonferroni tries to control FWER at the alpha level and simultaneous CIs are 100(1-alpha)% family-wise confidence intervals. So they have the FWER concept in common. But they are not equivalent. Why?

Comment: I looked at the documentation and at the source code a bit and I'm pretty sure multcomp computes only simultaneous (family-wise) CIs. I don't know of packages that implement FDR-corrected CIs. However, take a look at emmeans as an alternative to multcomp; I think it has a wider range of options.

Comment: Thank you again @dipetkov. I thought Bonferroni was a way of controlling for the family-wise error rate. I guess my next question is if multcomp doesn't use bonferroni for its family-wise error adjustment, what method *does* it use? Look you've done more than enough to get the bounty already, so you don't have to answer *another* follow-up. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Bonferroni does control the FWER but it's not *exact*: it guarantees that the FWER is ≤ α rather than = α. There are other methods designed for the same purpose; see [FWER controlling procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures). And the gap between the α we want and the α_B Bonferroni actually achieves can be quite big: α_B much smaller than α. This is what "convervative" means.

Comment: Also take a look at Chapter 13 in [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com).

Comment: Yes I am not a fan of bonferroni. You end up correcting out all your effects. I understand the need for Type-1 error control but not if you merely replace it with type 2 error. I have that book. I will take a look thank you.