# translating functions for correcting confidence intervals for familywise error rate from R,s multcomp package to Stata 17.0

Tags: r, stata, confidence-interval

My supervisor is an R user and I use Stata. He has asked me to correct confidence intervals from a regression model with several multi-level categorical predictors for multiple comparisons. He ran the model using the base `lm()` function, and then passed the regression object, first into the `glht()` function from the `multcomp` package, then into the `multcomp::confint()` function. His syntax looks like this.

```
mod <- lm(outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = df)

K <- length(mod$coefficients)
glhtMod <- glht(mod, linfct = diag(K))
 
confint(glhtMod, calpha = adjusted_calpha())
```

The key part of this code is the `calpha = adjusted_calpha()` argument, which simultaneously corrects all *k* confidence intervals from the model using the family-wise error rate.

As I said above, I do not use R and am not very experienced with coding. Can someone help point me towards the code in Stata that would deliver me similar results to the R code above?

I tried to use contrast with the `mcompare` function.

Comment: I’m not terribly conversant withe the ins and outs of multiple comparisons adjustment but you should see if this SO Q&A helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567990/correcting-confidence-intervals-for-multiple-comparisons-using-the-multcomp-pack?rq=2 .. It might be useful to run a parallel analysis on Stata to see whether you can demonstrate equivalence of methods that are accepted in your domain.